# Aren't old versions of Tor more stable at startup ? (Windows 64bit)

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration

I was running newest Tor version and every time Tor starts and builds the network to connect it always fails, sometimes I had to restart 2 times to get Tor to build the network correctly, I remember when using Tor 1 year ago this never ever happened, it always build the network on first try so now I decided to download version 9.5 and everything is ok, Tor builds the network on first try at start up, what is the way to totally disable update ?

Comment: Can you post your tor log here? Newer versions should be more stable than older versions, and older versions may no longer work correctly.

Comment: I can't right now, I uninstalled it, I'm running 9.5 now and no more problems at start up.